# How does package naming affects Android application once deployed?

Tags: android, deployment, naming-standards, packages, xamarin

Are there conventions to follow when naming an application package for an Android application?

I'm coding in Xamarin Studio, using .Net, so I feel far from this "com.myapp.etc" naming convention.

Are there rules to follow when naming an Android package?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The com.domain.myapp convention is to prevent namespace collision globally.  Android doesn't allow two packages of the same name, so you can't use a generic name.  If you don't have a web site for your app, a lot of people use com.github.myGithubUsername.myApp if they use github to host their version control.